# cmp.Equal gives panic message "cannot handle unexported field at .."

Tags: go, struct, comparison, go-cmp

I have a custom struct which has an unexported field. I want to be able to compare values with type of this struct, but I am receiving panic message like this:

```
panic: cannot handle unexported field at ...
consider using a custom Comparer; if you control the implementation of type, you can also consider using an Exporter, AllowUnexported, or cmpopts.IgnoreUnexported
```

Sample Code:

```golang
type MyType struct {
    ExpField int
    unexpField string
}

t1 := MyType{ExpField: 1}
t2 := MyType{ExpField: 2}
result := cmp.Equal(t1, t2)
```

How to fix this error and compare variables?

Answer (score 6):

As error message suggests, We can use `cmp.AllowUnexported` function. The important point here is as parameter we should use the type which **CONTAINS unexported field**, not the type of the unexported field.

So last line should be changed like this:

```golang
result := cmp.Equal(t1, t2, cmp.AllowUnexported(Mytype{}))
```

Also note that `cmp.AllowUnexported` doesn't work recursively for subtypes. If you have subtypes which contains unexported fields, you have to explicitly pass them.